# Haskell lookup function

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell, I want to build a function, where you pass an 'Int' and then return the list that is inside a list that contains that 'Int'. For example, say I have an 'Int' 3, and I have a list of multiple lists such as, [[1,2,6],[3,2,7],[5,7,8]]. I would return the block, "[3,2,7]" because it contains the value 3. How would I implement this in Haskell?

**function**

```
lookup :: Int -> [[Int]] -> [Int]
....
```

I tried using the built-in function "lookup" in Haskell, but this doesn't work because it uses tuples and it takes an index, and returns just the value of that index. I want a function that takes in a 'Int' value then searches a list of multiples list and returns the list that contains that value.

Comment: The signature does not make much sense: a list does not contain a comma, so `[a, b]` is not valid, and therefore neither is `[[a], [a]]`.

Comment: There are 3 cases: either the list is empty, `3` is in the head, or `3` may be in a list in the tail. Handle each case separately.

Comment: I wrote the incorrect type of the function

Comment: How do you check if it's on one of the lists? In terms of Haskell

Comment: You can use the built-in `elem`, which is trivial to implement yourself if you don't know about it. Again, either your list is empty, the head of list is your item, or your item might be in the tail.

Comment: What should be the result of `lookup 3 [[1,2,6],[3,2,7],[5,7,3,8]]`? And of `lookup 3 [[1,2,6],[2,7],[5,7,8]]` ? I.e. what if zero or more lists have 3 inside?

Answer (score 1):

The signature does not make much sense: a list does not contain a comma, so `[a, b]` is not valid, and therefore neither is `[[a], [a]]`.

Likely the signature should be something like:

```
lookup :: Eq a => a -> [[a]] -> [a]
```

or specific for an `Int`:

```
lookup :: Int -> [[Int]] -> [Int]
```

You can work with [**`elem :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:elem) to check if an element belongs to a certain list. This can then be used to *filter* the list with sublists, and return the (*first*) sublist that matches.